# what is the right brown border

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, iframe

here is my code....just paste it in a text.html and you will see a right brown border

```
<script src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>


<object width="480" height="270" border="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&amp;width=480&amp;height=270&amp;flashID=myExperience&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=605114004001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~%2CAAAAjCwoDiE~%2Cc_ahpRQZGGvLCf-ktkWpWZC8-D62skNH&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;autoStart=true&amp;debuggerID=&amp;videoID=817312565001&amp;%40videoPlayer=817312565001" id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience" seamlesstabbing="false"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="seamlessTabbing" value="false"><param name="swliveconnect" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="window"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"></object>
```

Is this the video or the setting ...why is that coming up

also you may have to refresh a few times because it changes to not being there and then being there ....really weird

Here is the code i use to generate because the top code was just for testing purposes

```
<a href="http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid605114004001?bctid=817312565001&iframe=true&width=499&height=280" rel='prettyPhoto[iframe]' title=""><img src="images/button.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Here is the [link](https://posnation.com/mercury/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code, leaving out the values in the `src` and `data` fields, and I didn't see a border. Must be something in either the javascript or the flash file. [Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/adAmU/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the  border is a background color that shows up when the width attribute of the object element is rendered larger than the max video width.  Reduce the width to 470 in either the object element's width attribute or the passed width parameter.  You will notice that your  first code snip-it uses the attribute and the second uses the parameter.